# VBA code: mistake on a Button to copy table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My boss asked me to code a little programm in vb.net so I am learning how this langage works but now I don't know where is my mistake.
My objectives are:

- past a folder link in a textbox (this step is ok)
- Create a button to read this link and select all files inside the selected folder and put files in a visible table (this step is ok too)
- Create a second button to copy/past each file to a new folder (I am here)

  My problem is that when i put a msgBox to see my containts inside this button I have nothing. Besides my table disappears when I am doing this step.
  Can you see what is my problem?? I am sure this is something stupid or maybe I don't anderstand something.
  Thanks a lot for your help

> Here my code

```
Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
Dim Link As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Protected Sub ButtonImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonImport.Click
Try
        path = TextBox1.Text
        Dim FileSystem = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        CreateTable(FileSystem.GetFolder(path))

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Protected Sub ButtonShipment_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonShipment.Click
    CopyFile()
End Sub

Sub CreateTable(ByRef Folder As Object)

    Dim File As Object
    Dim RepLivraison As String = Folder.Path
    Dim SubFolder As Object

    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        CreateTable(SubFolder)
    Next

    For Each File In Folder.Files

        Dim tRow As New TableRow()
        table1.Rows.Add(tRow)

        'Création d'une colonne avec le nom du fichier
        Dim tCell As New TableCell()
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell)
        tCell.Text = File.Name

        'Colonne de la zone de texte pour la destination du fichier
        Dim tCell2 As New TableCell()
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell2)

        'Mettre l'ID de la textbox ici pour chaque textbox !
        Dim txtbox As New TextBox
        tCell2.Controls.Add(txtbox)
        Dim FilePath As String = Replace(File.Path, path, "")
        txtbox.Text = Replace(FilePath, File.Name, "")

        'Colonne de la zone de texte pour la destination du fichier
        Dim tCell3 As New TableCell()
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell3)

        Dim ListAddRemove As New ListBox
        ListAddRemove.Items.Add("Ajouter")
        ListAddRemove.Items.Add("Supprimer")
        ListAddRemove.Items.Add("N/A")
        ListAddRemove.SelectedIndex = 0
        tCell3.Controls.Add(ListAddRemove)
    Next

End Sub



Public Sub CopyFile()
    MsgBox(Table1.Rows.Count)

    Dim targetPath As String
    'If CheckBox1.Checked Then
    'targetPath = "\\" & CheckBox1.Text & "\Wellview-10.1\Appli"
    'End If
    'Dim sourcePath As String = path
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        targetPath = "C:\Local\test\" & CheckBox1.Text
    End If

    ' Use Path class to manipulate file And directory paths.
    ' Dim sourceFile As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName)

    'Dim destFile As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName)

    ' To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
    ' Create a New target folder, if necessary.
    ' If (System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath)) Then

    'System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath)
    'End If


    ' To copy a file to another location And 
    ' overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
    'System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, True)


    For Each row As TableRow In table1.Rows
        Dim PathTarget As String = targetPath & table1.Rows.Item(2).ToString
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect that it needs `Dim PathTarget As String = targetPath & row.Item(2).ToString` in that For loop in `CopyFile()`.

Comment: Move `table1.Rows.Add(tRow)` before the `next`. `tRow` is empty after `New`, it's just created. Same for other `New TableCell`... A simple rule, create a variable->fill the variable-> use it.